# When is it a good idea to define a static ruby class?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, static, backend

Are there some governing rules around when it makes sense to define a static class as opposed to a class that is instantiated?

Still puzzling over idiomatic ruby initialization vs static class definition.

From what I've found.

Static classes seem very effective.

1. ruby is both a functional and object orientated language. it’s very possible to write both styles. a functional style is super useful for ‘functional’ things.
2. i regularly observe classes going from static to instantiated and then very quickly bloating. “now we have all this stuff.. why not do more?!“. i see instantiated classes have a natural tendency to unfortunately take expanding responsibilities.
3. i see that when a class transitions from static to instantiated we arrive at less unit testing confidence, given things at run time might change in regards to memory allocation / assignment (as in, someone could accidentally get in between instantiation and call).
4. i find that static classes are easier to read because we don’t have to juggle potential state change considerations. less mutation = less complexity.

For me. The big issues are:

1. Classes doing more than one thing.
2. Instability in patterns across large old ruby code bases.

To address these 2 concerns, I’m thinking a static approach (where possible) seems to put a healthy amount of pressure on the code to adhere to SOLID principles.

Static

```
Serializer.transform(fruit:)
```

Instantiated

```
Serializer.new(fruit:).transform
```

What drives you to go static in ruby?

Comment: Do you saw Service Objects pattern? I think this is what you say. And ruby community already use it.

Comment: Kahne, your question is a good one and very well-written. Unfortunately, it will probably be closed as being off-topic for SO (too broad). See SO's [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) page. (Don't feel bad.) Your question, "When is it a good idea to define a static ruby class?" is really mute, because there is no way to do that.

Comment: thanks for the head up! yes. it is broad.
i'm really looking for a list of governing principles around when to 'go static' and when NOT to 'go static'.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is a "static class"? There is no such thing as a "static class" in Ruby. In fact, there is almost nothing "static" at all in Ruby, almost everything is dynamically dispatched.

Comment: For the sake of this discussion. A “static class” in Ruby is a class that is not initialized. When does it pay to write in a “functional” way in Ruby? In this sense, how it is actully dispatches at run time seems like an orthogonal concern. I’m focusing on “design” optimization.

Answer (score 2):

What you are saying is that you want to use classes as nothing more than namespaces for pure functions.

There's nothing wrong with this, and you *can* use ruby this way, but you'll be going against the grain of the language in many ways.  This is a much longer discussion.

Also, I wouldn't frame this as static vs instantiated.  You're really asking about a pure functional vs an OO approach.  And finally, don't equate OO with "mutation."  You can use immutable value objects in ruby, and I recommend them.  You might want to check out the dry-rb ecosystem for a disciplined approach that advocates pure functional concepts in a way that is harmonious with ruby's natural support for objects.

Comment: Thanks Jonah. That is on point. I guess I’m hunting down thoughts on a how to build rails apps with a mix of both OO and Functional code. Some things we choose to initialize because they are shared or maintain state (like models) and some things we choose to make static because they are pure logic. I’m also stilling puzzling over this notion of “idiomatic” in the face of these deeper clean code concerns.

Comment: Will def check out dry-rb too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer copied from a colleague [CH].

I always like to benchmark some of these decisions:

```
require 'benchmark'

class ClassMethod
  def self.do_work
    1_000_000 * 1_000_000
  end
end

class InstanceMethod
  def do_work
    1_000_000 * 1_000_000
  end
end

class InstanceMethodHiddenByClassMethod
  def self.do_work
    new.do_work
  end

  def do_work
    1_000_000 * 1_000_000
  end
end

iterations = 10_000_000

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("class method") do
    iterations.times do
      ClassMethod.do_work
    end
  end

  x.report("instance method") do
    iterations.times do
      InstanceMethod.new.do_work
    end
  end

  x.report("class hiding instance pattern") do
    iterations.times do
      InstanceMethodHiddenByClassMethod.do_work
    end
  end
end
```

Results

```
user                           system     total      real
class method                   0.520000   0.010000   0.530000 (  0.531997)
instance method                1.130000   0.000000   1.130000 (  1.131185)
class hiding instance pattern  1.270000   0.010000   1.280000 (  1.282921)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Governing principles?

When to write a static ruby class:

- when it's there to encapsulate a simple piece of logic with few inputs. things like "serializing a model" or making a "business decision" with a single param.
- when memory management scale is a critical concern.

When to write a ruby class that is intended to be initialize:

- when it requires persistence. (e.g. active record models)
- when it's common piece of code (with multiple parameters) that is often injection.
- when it's 'orchestration or routing' logic with injected dependencies.

Whatever the case. It seems important to me that teams get together and outline what recurring patterns are intended to be static or instantiated across their dependency graph.